# Basis vectors and bounded spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need you help in understanding the following:

Let $C = \left\lbrace v\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \left\| v\right\| \leq 100  \right\rbrace$, and let let $B \subseteq C$ a set of $n$ independent vectors such that for each $v \in C$, $\left\| v\right\| = 100$.
Let $\{ \alpha_i\} _{i = 1}^n$ be scalars .

Then is is true that for every $u \in C$, it can be represented by linear combination of the vectors in $B$ using $\{ \alpha_i\} _{i = 1}^n$ while for every $i \in [n]$, $\left| \alpha_i\right| \leq 1$?

In other words, are the scalars used to obtain linear combination using the basis $B$ at max $1$ and at min $-1$?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused with your definition of $B$.  $B$ is a set of $n$ independent vectors such that what?  Each of their magnitudes is 100?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false even in two dimensions.
Let $B=\{(100,0), (100/\sqrt{2},100/\sqrt{2})\}$.
You cannot write $(0,100)$ as a linear combination of these vectors if the coefficients are forced to lie in $[-1,1]$.

---

However, if the basis $B = \{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ is orthogonal, then your claim is true because the set of vectors of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$ where $|\alpha_i| \le 1$ is an $n$-dimensional hypercube centered at the origin with edge length $200$, which contains $C$.

Comment: nice, i did not type that the vectors are also orthogonal to each other. Is there a way to show that the scalars used in the linear combination will also be positive even though i dont think that would even occur but what conditions should we impose on the C or B such that we might obtain such linear combination?

Comment: * i meant to write that the vectors are orthogonal as well.

Comment: @user3492773 You should draw some pictures. If you force the scalars to be positive, then you can only get vectors in a particular orthant of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but $C$ contains vectors in all orthants.

Comment: I see, so if i concatenate the negative of $B$ to $B$ then i will achieve convex combination rather than linear combination right?

Comment: @angryavian sorry but I do not understand your point. $B=\{(100,0), (100/\sqrt{2},100/\sqrt{2})\}$ are independent vectors, so those two can span a 2D space. I can achieve $(0,100) = -1*(100,0) + 1/\sqrt{2} * (100/\sqrt{2},100/\sqrt{2})$. Does something wrong with my math?

Comment: @koralgooll Your right-hand side equals $(-50, 50)$. If your second coefficient were $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $1/\sqrt{2}$ then yes that would equal $(0, 100)$. But $\sqrt{2}$ is not in $[-1, 1]$.